# How to generate an wave with some slope?

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing, slope

I want to generate this wave with an slope

[image]

I believe that is a kind of amplitude modulation with some slope: $y(t) = [A_c + A_m \sin(ω_m \ t)] \sin(ω_c \ t)$. After plot the AM equation I get the following image:

[image]What function can I apply to  AM equation to get the slope? Or is there another way to generate the plot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFdmj.png)?

Comment: Add the trend function $h(t)=at$ where $a>0$ is the slope

Comment: Find the maximum points seen so far working left to right. Then find the minimum points working right to left. Fit a line to each sets of points which will give you two lines as an envelope. The line half way between these lines should approximate your slope.

Comment: Alternatively, do a discrete cosine transform, or wavelet transform, on the data, zero out the higher frequencies, and leave the low ones. Then inverse transform and fit a line to the result.

Comment: The suggestion done by @Snoop works.